# Two dates comparing

Tags: java

I am trying to compare to dates . I already found some topics about that but it doesn't work for me and I don't know why. For example I tried to compare using methods like "compareTo , after, before" but it does't work. What can I do? I am receiving the error `compareTo(java.lang.String)` in string cannot be applied to `(java.util.Date)`. What can I do?  I want to make modification just starting with class EvenimentRecurent.

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
class Eveniment {
    private Date dataInceput, dataSfarsit;
    private String nume;

    public Eveniment() {
    }

    public Eveniment(String dataInceput, String dataSfarsit, String nume) {
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        try {
            this.dataInceput = format.parse(dataInceput);
            this.dataSfarsit = format.parse(dataSfarsit);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Data nu este in formatul cerut!");
        }

        this.nume = nume;
    }

    public Date getDataInceput() {
        return dataInceput;
    }

    public Date getDataSfarsit() {
        return dataSfarsit;
    }

    public String getNume() {
        return nume;
    }
}

class EvenimentRecurent extends Eveniment {
    private Date dataP;
    public int numarOre;


    public  EvenimentRecurent(String dataInceput, String dataSfarsit, String nume, int numarOre){
        super(dataInceput,dataSfarsit,nume);
        this.numarOre=numarOre;


    }
    private static final DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:s");
    public String urmatorulEveniment(String dataP){
        Date neww;
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        try {
            this.dataP = format.parse(dataP);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Data nu este in formatul cerut!");

        }
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            c.setTime(this.dataP);
            while(dataP.compareTo(getDataSfarsit()))
            c.add(Calendar.HOUR, numarOre);
            Date currentDatePlusOne = c.getTime();
            String strDate = dateFormat.format(currentDatePlusOne);
        return strDate;
    }
}
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EvenimentRecurent er = new EvenimentRecurent("2019-03-09 22:46:00", "2019-03-09 23:00:00", "Scris probleme", 24);
        System.out.println(er.urmatorulEveniment("2019-04-19 22:46:23"));
        // 2019-04-20 22:46:23

    }
}
```

Comment: "enter code here"? Do you want us to enter code there? Not gonna happen. It's a guide to *you* to enter code there, instead of linking to the code. Please fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in this statement

```
dataP.compareTo(getDataSfarsit())
```

First of all, change *dataP* to *this.dataP*, so the statement will be: `dataP.compareTo(getDataSfarsit())`

Second, you should Know that the compareTo method of the java.util.Date class returns an int, and this is what the javadoc says: "*the value 0 if the argument Date is equal to this Date; a value less than 0 if this Date is before the Date argument; and a value greater than 0 if this Date is after the Date argument.*" In this case your condition should be like the following:

```
while(this.dataP.compareTo(getDataSfarsit())==0)
```

That's all, hope this will be helpful :)

Answer (score 2):

This is a possible solution, I prefer to use number format.

```
try {
    SimpleDateFormat formatoDeFecha = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

    String fecha1 = "20/05/2019";
    String fecha2 = "19/05/2019";

    Date dFecha1 = formatoDeFecha.parse(fecha1);
    Date dFecha2 = formatoDeFecha.parse(fecha2);

    if(dFecha1.getTime()==dFecha2.getTime()){
        System.out.println("Fechas iguales");
    }
    else if(dFecha1.getTime()<dFecha2.getTime()){
        System.out.println("Fecha 1 menor a fecha 2");
    }
    else if(dFecha1.getTime()>dFecha2.getTime()){
        System.out.println("Fecha 1 mayor a fecha 2");
    }
} catch (ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I hope that this help you.